# How is this a draw?

Tags: rules, draw

I was playing a game on chess.com. It is this game: https://www.chess.com/live/game/84265198943
It ended in a draw right as I was about to flag my opponent. I can not figure out why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three-fold repetition. The position facing Black for their 61st, 63rd, and 65th moves was exactly the same.

Comment: Always nice to add some reference. The FIDE Handbook section about the Laws of Chess state this in Article 9. §9.2 mentions: `The game is drawn upon a correct claim by the player having the move, when the same position, for at least the third time (not necessarily by a repetition of moves) is about to appear [...] or has just appeared[...].`